# How to show word suggestion bar on a ios keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm implementing a custom keyboard and I need to show the suggestion bar (the one that shows words suggestions as you type).

Do I have to implement it myself or there is any mechanism to show a built-in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`QuickType`](https://www.apple.com/uk/ios/whats-new/quicktype/), which is the feature that shows suggested words above iOS keyboards, is available only on standard keyboards. So it cannot be shown in your custom keyboard extension.

Comment: That's bad news. Do you know any component I could use? I've seen keyboards as TouchPal implementing this feature

Comment: I've seen that one but my problem is that I'm using swift and that component was done with objective c:( Maybe I can convert it to a library and consume it from my project. Thanks